# Corresponding value in json document

Tags: scala, json4s

Suppose I have 2 json documents of similar structure:

```
A. {"a:"{"b": 42}}
B. {"a":{"b": 1}}
```

My task is to find corresponding path in first document while having path of second document. For example, let find the diff of these 2 docuemnts: `A diff B`.
the result will be the document {"a":{"b":1}}. The problem is to find the old value of `a.b` key in document A. Documents can have arbitrary structure(but structure is same for 2 comparing documents)

**EDIT** after having `val diff = A.diff(B)` how to get the document of such structure(or even whithout having `diff`)?

```
{"a":
   {"b": 
      {"old": 42, "new": 1}
    }
 }
```

Comment: At least to me, it's very unclear what you're actually after here.

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: Well, that's not helped much.  You now state two different results for A diff B - one is just B, and one is a sort of merge. Maybe someone else can work out what you mean, I don't see it.

Comment: You now state two different results for A diff B - one is just B - If you think so, then you don't know how `diff` works. It returns a `Diff` object with `changed`, `added` and `removed` values. While `added` and `removed` will be empty, `changed` will contain the diff between A and B which is obviously(in this case) just a B, but I said that documents can have any structure also.